# Get value on table a where table b value = table c

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 tables, `BOOKDETAILS`, `LOANEDBOOK` AND `BORROWER`.

```
CREATE TABLE BOOKDETAILS
(
    ISBN_NO BIGINT NOT NULL,
    PUBLICATION_YEAR INT NOT NULL,
    TITLE varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    AUTHOR varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    PUBLISHER varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    CATEGORY varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(ISBN_NO)
);

CREATE TABLE BORROWER
(
    BORROWER_NO INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    BORROWER_NAME VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    BORROWER_IC VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    BORROWER_PHONENO VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    BORROWER_ADDRESS VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    BORROWER_N0_BOOKS INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (BORROWER_NO)
)

CREATE TABLE LOANEDBOOK
(
    BORROWER_NO INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES BORROWER(BORROWER_NO),
    ISBN_NO BIGINT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES BOOKDETAILS(ISBN_NO),
    ISSUE_DATE DATE NOT NULL,
    DUE_DATE DATE NOT NULL
)
```

- `BOOKDETAILS` is related to `LOANEDBOOK` (PK/FK = ISBN_NO)
- `BORROWER` is related to `LOANEDBOOK` (PK/FK = BORROWER_ID)

I need to get the title from table `BOOKDETAILS` using `BORROWER_ID`.

How do I write a query to get the value of `Title`?

Comment: As a beginner I suggest finding some tutorials and having a go. There is no advantage to you having someone here write your query for you. Find a good tutorial, have a go, then post a question when you get stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need `INNER JOIN` as follows:

```
select bd.TITLE
  from LOANEDBOOK lb 
  join BOOKDETAILS bd on lb.ISBN = bd.ISBN
 where lb.BORROWER_NO = 123;
```

You should learn the joins as a beginner. Hope this answer will be helpful to you in learning the basic join.